# Salesforce Platform API Versions 21.0 through 30.0 Retirement

Tags: api, rest, developer-console

I received an email "Salesforce Platform API Versions 7.0 through 30.0 Retirement".
I am new to my org and I managed to see the list of installed packages,
I then run a query to get the list of the latest used APIs using the Developer console ( Salesforce CLI  not working for me ) but now I am at loss when it comes to determine if requests are being made to endpoints with API versions 30 and below.
the article linked to the email suggests to run a rest on the results of the log is there a way of doing this in the developer console since  Salesforce CLI  is not working for me ?
Thank you all in advance
Valentina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [Event Log browser](https://salesforce-elf.herokuapp.com/), which allows you to query the mentioned categories, and download them as CSV files. So, you can open them in Excel or Google Sheets and check the API version of the request URLs.

To learn more, you can check this [module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring/event_monitoring_query) on Trailhead.

Comment: this is brilliant thank you!